# SyntaxError: invalid syntax in running python kafka code

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-kafka

I am running a code in python 3.7,
the library is installed by

```
pip3 install kafka
```

here is the code

```
import random
import time, calendar
from random import randint
from kafka import KafkaProducer
from kafka import errors
from json import dumps
from time import sleep


def write_data(producer):
    data_cnt = 20000
    order_id = calendar.timegm(time.gmtime())
    max_price = 100000
    topic = "payment_msg"

    for i in range(data_cnt):
        ts = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime())
        rd = random.random()
        order_id += 1
        pay_amount = max_price * rd
        pay_platform = 0 if random.random() < 0.9 else 1
        province_id = randint(0, 6)
        cur_data = {"createTime": ts, "orderId": order_id, "payAmount": pay_amount, "payPlatform": pay_platform, "provinceId": province_id}
        producer.send(topic, value=cur_data)
        sleep(0.5)

def create_producer():
    print("Connecting to Kafka brokers")
    for i in range(0, 6):
        try:
            producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['kafka:9092'],
                            value_serializer=lambda x: dumps(x).encode('utf-8'))
            print("Connected to Kafka")
            return producer
        except errors.NoBrokersAvailable:
            print("Waiting for brokers to become available")
            sleep(10)

    raise RuntimeError("Failed to connect to brokers within 60 seconds")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    producer = create_producer()
    write_data(producer)
```

however an error is showing up

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generate_source_data.py", line 22, in <module>
    from kafka import KafkaProducer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kafka/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from kafka.producer import KafkaProducer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kafka/producer/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .simple import SimpleProducer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kafka/producer/simple.py", line 54
    return '<SimpleProducer batch=%s>' % self.async
```

what is the problem?

Comment: Are you sure that's the full text of the traceback?

Comment: yes, that is everything i got in the console

Comment: Where does it say SyntaxError?

Answer (score 8):

I found the answer from here https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python/issues/1566.

`pip3 uninstall kafka` to remove the kafka package and install it by `pip3 install kafka-python`

Comment: Thank you! Any idea why this occurs?